# Jquery ajax with json parsing issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http:abc/public/aditya/eJewelry/get_store_details.php?store_id=udb1001',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

I am sending request to that url and getting responce:-

```
[{
    "id": "22",
    "storename": "Unique Diamond Boutique",
    "email": "croberts@uniquediamondboutique.com",
    "storeimage_ipad": "",
    "website": "www.uniquediamondboutique.com",
    "store_code": "udb1001",
    "street_address": "157 E New England Avenue\nSuite 202\n",
    "country": "US",
    "zipcode": "32789",
    "state": "FL",
    "city": "Winter Park",
    "email_sales": "croberts@parkavegold.com",
    "personal_phone": "407-312-6768",
    "company_phone": "407-218-5958",
    "image": "store_22.png",
    "status": "1",
    "paypal_email": "croberts@uniquediamondboutique.com",
    "moreAddress": [{
        "street_address": "123 main st",
        "city": "MIAMI",
        "state": "FL",
        "zipcode": "33106",
        "country": "",
        "website": "",
        "id": "68",
        "company_phone": "",
        "company_email": ""
    }, {
        "street_address": "640 Brevard Ave",
        "city": "Cocoa Beach",
        "state": "FL",
        "zipcode": "32922",
        "country": "",
        "website": " ",
        "id": "69",
        "company_phone": "407-123-5678",
        "company_email": " "
    }]
}]
```

When i use alert(data) i am getting "[object Object]";

How can i use that data to get the id, country,email_sales..etc.

I am using alert(data.id) but getting empty alert. If you have any idea kindly let me know.

Comment: It's an array of objects so data[0].id

Comment: If I got you right, you wanted to log all properties, not just the ID, right? I've added an answer which lists all properties of the data object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your success function use `$.each()` to get the objects:

```
success: function (data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, item){  // get in the array to have objects
        console.log(item.id); // logs 22, 
        $.each(item.moreAddress, function(_, resp){ // here get one more level deep
            console.log(resp.id); // logs 68, 69
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It is because `data` is an array of objects, whose default `toString()` implementation returns  `[object Object]`.

To see the value of a object instead of `alert()` use `console.log()`([developer console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console)).

Since data is an array, you need to iterate through it to get the values like. Since you are using jQuery you can use [$.each()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each) to do that(you can otherwise use a normal loop statement or [Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)).

```
$.each(data, function(i, item){
    console.log(item.id)
})
```

Comment: I'm sure @Arun answers these *before* they're asked! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
alert(data[0].id);
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

The answers I have seen so far are just giving you back the value of the ID, not of every property.
Try this, it will print the object items to the console:

```
function listObject(obj) {
    $.each(obj, function(i, item1){
        console.log('obj['+i+'] contents:');
        $.each(item1, function(j, item2){
              console.log(j+'='+JSON.stringify(item2))
        });    
    });
};

listObject(data);
```

For demonstration, I have created a [Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sAxKN/1/).
It will output  (press **F12** in **Internet Explorer** to get console output - then click the **console tab**):

```
LOG: obj[0] contents: 
LOG: id="22" 
LOG: storename="Unique Diamond Boutique" 
LOG: email="croberts@uniquediamondboutique.com" 
LOG: storeimage_ipad="" 
LOG: website="www.uniquediamondboutique.com" 
LOG: store_code="udb1001" 
LOG: street_address="157 E New England Avenue\nSuite 202\n" 
LOG: country="US" 
LOG: zipcode="32789" 
LOG: state="FL" 
LOG: city="Winter Park" 
LOG: email_sales="croberts@parkavegold.com" 
LOG: personal_phone="407-312-6768" 
LOG: company_phone="407-218-5958" 
LOG: image="store_22.png" 
LOG: status="1" 
LOG: paypal_email="croberts@uniquediamondboutique.com" 
LOG: moreAddress=[{"street_address":"123 main st","city":"MIAMI","state":"FL","zipcode":"33106","country":"","website":"","id":"68","company_phone":"","company_email":""},
        {"street_address":"640 Brevard Ave","city":"Cocoa Beach","state":"FL","zipcode":"32922","country":"","website":" ","id":"69","company_phone":"407-123-5678","company_email":" "}
        ]
```

You can also make the function recursive to traverse the entire object but I think this approach is simple enough for what you need.